# How do you play identical audio twice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm building a DTMF dial emulator. After a certain function runs, the function dial() is executed. Currently, I hear the ringback tone once but I cannot get it to ring twice.

I originally tried to get the same file to play twice by resetting the audio currentTime to 0 and playing it again after a delay of 4 seconds (the duration between ringback tones in North America).

That didn't work so I thought perhaps JS didn't want me playing the same audio twice. So I recreated it again as a second variable and created a new function for that next in the sequence for dial().

That didn't work, but if I added an alert box before ringingTone2 played, it played as soon as I dismissed the alert.

Obviously, I can't have an alert dialog when this is done. How can I have the sound play twice, but with a 4 second gap in between? I've had no success with `setTimeout(ring(), 4000)` either.

Here is some of the code pertaining to this issue:

```
    var ringingTone1 = new Audio('DTMF-ringbackTone.mp3');
    var ringingTone2 = new Audio('DTMF-ringbackTone.mp3');
    function dial() {
        ring();
        function ring() {
            ringingTone1.play();
            setTimeout(ringingTone2.play(),4000);
        }
```

Right now, JS basically plays the ringback tone once and moves onto to what is after this in the script.

The following causes it to stop working:

```
function dial() {
        ring();
        function ring() {
            var played = 0;
            var maxPlay = 2;

            var ringingTone = document.getElementById('music');
            var playBtn = document.getElementById('playbtn');

            ringingTone.onplay = ring() {
              //played counter
              played++;
            };
            ringingTone.addEventListener("ended", ring() {
              //reset to start point
              ringingTone.currentTime = 0;
              if (played < maxPlay) {
                ringingTone.play();
              } else {
                played = 0;
              }
            });
            playBtn.addEventListener("click", ring() {
              ringingTone.play();
            });
        }
```

This is my complete script:

```
var availableNumbers = ["0", "911"];
    function numberSuggestion() {
        var randomNumber = Math.random() * availableNumbers.length -1;
        var suggestedNumber = availableNumbers[randomNumber];
        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = "How about dialing " + suggestedNumber + "? Don't like this number? Click the button above again!";
    }
    var dialTone;
    function offHook() {
        document.getElementById("WE2500").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dialPad").style.display = "block";
        dialTone = new Audio('dialTone.m4a');
        dialTone.play();
    }
    var number = "";
    var timeout;
    function numberDial() {
        if (dialTone) {
            dialTone.pause();
            dialTone.currentTime = 0;
        }
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(dial, 2000);
    }
    function dial1() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "1";
        var tone1 = new Audio('DTMF-1.wav');
        tone1.play();
    }
    function dial2() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "2";
        var tone2 = new Audio('DTMF-2.wav');
        tone2.play();
    }
    function dial3() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "3";
        var tone3 = new Audio('DTMF-3.wav');
        tone3.play();
    }
    function dial4() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "4";
        var tone4 = new Audio('DTMF-5.wav');
        tone4.play();
    }
    function dial5() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "5";
        var tone5 = new Audio('DTMF-5.wav');
        tone5.play();
    }
    function dial6() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "6";
        var tone6 = new Audio('DTMF-6.wav');
        tone6.play();
    }
    function dial7() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "7";
        var tone7 = new Audio('DTMF-7.wav');
        tone7.play();
    }
    function dial8() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "8";
        var tone8 = new Audio('DTMF-8.wav');
        tone8.play();
    }
    function dial9() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "9";
        var tone9 = new Audio('DTMF-9.wav');
        tone9.play();
    }
    function dial0() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "0";
        var tone0 = new Audio('DTMF-0.wav');
        tone0.play();
    }
    function dialStar() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "*";
        var toneStar = new Audio('DTMF-star.wav');
        toneStar.play();
    }
    function dialPound() {
        numberDial();
        number = number + "#";
        var tonePound = new Audio('DTMF-pound.wav');
        tonePound.play();
    }
    //var ringingTone1 = new Audio('DTMF-ringbackTone.mp3');
    //var ringingTone2 = new Audio('DTMF-ringbackTone.mp3');
    function dial() {
        ring();
        function ring() {
            var played = 0;
            var maxPlay = 2;

            var ringingTone = document.getElementById('music');
            var playBtn = document.getElementById('playbtn');

            ringingTone.onplay = ring() {
              //played counter
              played++;
            };
            ringingTone.addEventListener("ended", ring() {
              //reset to start point
              ringingTone.currentTime = 0;
              if (played < maxPlay) {
                ringingTone.play();
              } else {
                played = 0;
              }
            });
            playBtn.addEventListener("click", ring() {
              ringingTone.play();
            });
        }
        switch(number) {
            case "0":
                break;
            case "911":
                var pickup911 = new Audio('911-xxx-fleet.mp3');
                pickup911.play();
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

Comment: An idea (perhaps stupid): why don't you play 4 seconds of silence?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte is just the ringing tone for 2 seconds. And what if I wanted to play it 3 times? There isn't a file for every combination of number of rings. I know it can be done in JS

Comment: Does it help if you remove the (): `setTimeout(ringingTone2.play,4000);`

Comment: @yezzz No, still doesn't work - no difference

Comment: *"Currently, I hear the ringback tone once but I cannot get it to ring twice."* : I think your ring is designed to be looped, that is why you hear it only once, but I suspect that it is two time longer. That's why I suggest to play silence between each ring.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The ring is an audio file and I listened to it in WMP. 2 seconds long

Comment: And what is the ring duration with your script?

Comment: Same as audio file - just once

Comment: Set timeout takes a function: `setTimeout(function() {ringingTone2.play()}, 4000);`

Comment: @BitByte Didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a function in setTimeout (and I think it applies to all callbacks) using () will cause the code inside to be evaluated immediately (which in your case meant play both audios at the same time).

Hence my comment above to use `.play` without (), which looks like doesn't work. However, this does work:

```
function dial() {
  function ring() {
    ringingTone.play();
  }
  ring();
  setTimeout(ring, 4000);
}
dial();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tL3monyp/

(audio src unscrupulously copied from Daniel's answer ;-)

I've also added 2 timeouts to illustrate calling the function with and without ().

Comment: I got the 2 rings, but the 2nd ring does not function before JS proceeds to the next thing (which is more audio so that's a no-no). How can I force JS to finish one function before moving to the next? Why is it executing functions in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is simple, one counter for played time, one constant for max play.

Use the `onplay` event to increase the counter everytime a audio played.

Use the `ended` event to replay the audio if max play time not reached yet. Otherwise, set played count to 0.

```js
var played = 0;
var maxPlay = 2;

var ringingTone = document.getElementById('music');
var playBtn = document.getElementById('playbtn');

ringingTone.onplay = function() {
  //played counter
  played++;
};

ringingTone.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  //reset to start point
  ringingTone.currentTime = 0;
  if (played < maxPlay) {
    ringingTone.play();
  } else {
    played = 0;
  }
});

playBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ringingTone.play();
});
```

```html
<audio id="music" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3732.mp3"></audio>

<button id="playbtn">Play me</button>
```

Comment: I see where this is going, but this just totally stopped up my script. Now all the other JS (hundreds of lines) doesn't execute. Nothing works.

Comment: @InterLinked ok I updated again, it is more dynamic now, each time you play it play 2 time then reset, you can play again by click the btn.

Comment: @InterLinked I updated my answer, the way you use `ring()` I never saw before

Comment: @InterLinked to make recursive call you can just call `ring()` at the end of a function.